# Host '192.168.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql

So basically I'm trying to configure mysql master-slave replication and have been following [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-configure-mysql-8-0-master-slave-replication-on-ubuntu-18-04/) manual.

My problem is that I cannot connect my app to the db. Probably one important thing to note here is that I did not comment out the line setting the `bind-address` parameter and instead changed its value from `127.0.0.1` to `192.168.1.91`.

However I don't really see how it would relate to the issue I'm currently facing. I'm also unable to connect to it remotely using something like:

```
mysql -u myuser -h 192.16.1.91 -p
```

I'm using Ubuntu server 18.04 on both nodes.

I know this question has already been asked a number of times but I tend to believe that this case is somewhat special.

**EDIT 1:**

Here's how I created a new user on the master node:

```
create user myuser@192.168.1.147 identified by '1qaz2wsx3edc';
```

and then to grant privileges:

```
grant replication slave on *.* to myuser@192.168.1.147;
flash privileges;
```

Comment: This error is unrelated to your master/slave or bind-address setup. You need to create a user and give that user permission to connect from the machine you want to connect the client(or app)  from, have you done this ? (Can you post the SQL you did run to create the `myuser` user ?

Comment: MySQL is telling you that host isn't permitted because of ACLs, not because of the address you're binding to.  It's a completely separate issue.    Did you change the addresses shown in that guide to your own addresses from their examples of @10.131.35.167 ?

Comment: @nos yes, I understand that. To create a new user I ran the script specified in the manual I referenced to. I will post it in my edit in a minute.

Comment: @Alnitak oh sorry, I missed your comment. Yes, I did change the addresses indeed. So as far as I understand it has nothing to do with the addresses, then how do I fix it?

Comment: BTW, this isn't on-topic for this site.  It's not a programming quesiton.

Comment: @Alnitak So you do not know, correct?

Comment: @GoBear The manual you link to is setting up a user that is to be used for replication purposes. The error you get is not related to the replication you have been setting up.  You need to create a user for yourself and/or your application too - there's numerous tutorials on how to create users in mysql.

Comment: @nos yes, that's exactly what I need cos I'm configuring a mysql replica set. However with the help of others I managed to figure out what I was doing wrong. I was creating a user that were not able to access the db from a remote host. It should have been user@192.168.1.%.